# 'The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage'

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-conversion

I am having some troubles with generics and inheritance. I have an abstract class called `CriteriaBase` whose job it is to determine if an entity `T` matches the criteria defined in  any sub-classes. The sub-classes have to implement a method which returns a `Func` representing the criteria. The problem arises when I try to use generics for the `Func`. Hopefully some code will illustrate my problem.

```
public abstract class CriteriaBase<T, U>
    where T : ICrossoverable
    where U : IChromosome
{
    protected abstract Func<U, bool> Criteria { get; }
    //some code removed for brevity

    private int GetNumberOfCriteriaMatches(T season)
    {
        //1.  works
        //Func<IChromosome, bool> predicate = c => c.Genes == null;
        //return season.Chromosomes.Count(predicate);

        //2.  doesn't work - The type arguments for method 'int 
        //System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, 
        //Func<TSource, bool>)'
        //cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments 
        //explicitly.
        return season.Chromosomes.Count(Criteria);
    }
}
```

My intention is that the `CriteriaBase` class should be generic and completely reusable.

An example sub-class:

```
public class TopTeamsPlayingEachOtherCriteria : CriteriaBase<Season, MatchDay>
{
    //some code removed for brevity

    protected override Func<MatchDay, bool> Criteria
    {
        get { return matchDay =>
            matchDay.Fixtures.Count(
                fixture =>
                fixture.HomeTeam.TableGrouping.Ordering == 1 
                && fixture.AwayTeam.TableGrouping.Ordering == 1) > 1; }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `GetNumberOfCriteriaMatches()` method. Option 2 is how I originally wrote the code but I get the compile error as listed. If I use option 1 then the code compiles but it means that when I override `Criteria` in the sub-class, I have to use `IChromosome` instead of `MatchDay` which doesn't work (I need to access specific features of a `MatchDay`). In my simple mind, options 1 and 2 are equivalent. Option 2 simply replaces `IChromosome` with a generic type `U` which is restricted to a class that implements `IChromosome`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If so, what am I missing/misunderstanding? If not, how should I approach this problem?

For completeness (included at the end as I'm not sure how much it helps with the question), here are the two entities that I'm currently using for `T` (`Season`) and `U` (`MatchDay`).

```
public class Season : ICrossoverable
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<MatchDay> _matchDays;

    public Season(IEnumerable<MatchDay> matchDays)
    {
        _matchDays = matchDays;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MatchDay> MatchDays
    {
        get { return _matchDays; }
    }

    //ICrossoverable implementation
    public IEnumerable<IChromosome> Chromosomes
    {
        get { return _matchDays; }
    }
}

public class MatchDay : IChromosome
{
    private readonly int _week;
    private readonly List<Fixture> _fixtures;

    public MatchDay(int week, List<Fixture> fixtures)
    {
        _week = week;
        _fixtures = fixtures;
    }

    //some code removed for brevity

    public IEnumerable<Fixture> Fixtures
    {
        get { return _fixtures; }
    }

    //IChromosome implementation
    public IEnumerable<IGene> Genes
    {
        get { return Fixtures; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .net framework do you use?

Comment: .NET version 4 - the full version not the client profile. Does the answer differ depending on the version? Using Visual Studio 2010 if that's interesting.

Comment: Delegate covariance and contravariance is working in c# from version 4.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this is the problem:

```
public IEnumerable<IChromosome> Chromosomes
```

You're *only* declaring that you're returning a sequence of `IChromosome` values. Your criterion expects `MatchDay` values. *You* happen to know that it's actually returning a sequence of `MatchDay` values, but the compiler doesn't.

You could use `Cast<>` to check this at execution time:

```
return season.Chromosomes.Cast<U>().Count(Criteria);
```

... or you could change `Chromosomes` to return an `IEnumerable<MatchDay>`. Unfortunately we can't really tell whether that's a valid answer or not as we don't know how `ICrossoverable` is declared. Perhaps you should make `ICrossoverable` generic in the element type?

Comment: Ah ha! That clears it up. I think the actual solution lies in your last sentence - make `ICrossoverable` generic. I will try this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: As suggested, I made `ICrossoverable` generic which solved my problem. The code is in [my Github repository](https://github.com/hungryhippo2312/GeneticAlgorithm). I renamed ICrossoverable to IOrganism as it fits much better with the genetic algorithm terminology. An implementation of `CriteriaBase<TOrganism, TChromosome> can be found [in another Github repository](https://github.com/hungryhippo2312/FixtureGenerator/blob/master/FixtureGenerator/Criteria/SuperSundayCriteria.cs). Thanks for the multiple and varied suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You should use keyword `in` before U in CriteriaBase definition. Something like this:

```
public abstract class CriteriaBase<T, in U>
    where T : ICrossoverable
    where U : IChromosome
```

**Update**. It will not work. 
Try to specify type explicitly

```
private int GetNumberOfCriteriaMatches(T season)
{
 ....
    return season.Chromosomes.Count<IChromosome>(Criteria);
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get a compiler error saying 'Variant type parameters could be declared in interfaces or delegates only'. Three questions: what does adding `in` do, what does this error mean and why doesn't it work? Thanks!

Comment: I forget that this could works only for delegates and interfaces. Ok. Than try to specify explicitly Count<IChromosome>(Criteria)

Comment: Now have a different error! 'Argument type 'System.Func<U, bool>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<GeneticAlgorithm.IChromosome, bool>'. It's almost as if 'where U : IChromosome' doesn't exist! Where now?

Comment: I have no new ideas... Try to summon Jon Skeet here.